# Drawing order in HTML canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw some circles with numbers on top of them, in a `for` loop. But for some reason numbers end up behind circles: https://jsfiddle.net/6c3yfLou/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember `beginPath()` - this will clear the current path. Otherwise all previous added arcs will be filled every time fill() is called.

```
c.beginPath();
c.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
...
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/6c3yfLou/3/)**